# Reasoning about boost mpl placeholders

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

The [Tutorial: Metafunctions and Higher-Order Metaprogramming](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/implementing-division.html) section of the Boost MPL library documentation states that `transform` can be invoked like so

```
typename mpl::transform<D1,D2, mpl::minus<_1,_2> >::type
```

where the placeholders `_1` and `_2` signify that when the transform's `BinaryOperation` is invoked, its first and second arguments will be passed on to minus in the positions indicated by `_1` and `_2`, respectively.

I've been reading this over and over again for almost a month and I still don't understand it.

What values exactly do the placeholders `_1` and `_2` have? `D1` and `D2`? If so, why not write `mpl::minus<D1,D2>`? Also considering that the placeholders are [defined as](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/placeholders.html) `typedef arg<1> _1;` and `typedef arg<2> _2;` and consequently the original expression *in my mind* amounts to

```
typename mpl::transform<D1,D2, mpl::minus<<arg<1>,<arg<2> > >::type
```

I'm sure I'm thinking about placeholders the wrong way. I'd appreciate some guidance here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, you're thinking about placeholders the wrong way.

`mpl::minus` is a template in MPL's metalanguage that symbolically *represents* (or *corresponds to*) a certain high-level behavior, namely, subtraction. You're thinking of it as if it's a non-meta construct such as a function

```
int minus(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
```

but it's not. (The standard C++11 library does have something kind of like that, called [`std::minus<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/minus_void), but that's ***not*** what `mpl::minus` does!)

`mpl::minus` *represents* the subtraction operation at a *higher level of abstraction*. Don't worry for another couple of paragraphs about how `mpl::minus` is implemented. Just think about what it *represents*, which is subtraction of two things.

Ah, but which two things? Well, `mpl::minus` lets you specify those things as template parameters. For example,

```
mpl::minus<mpl::int_<7>, mpl::int_<3>>
```

expands to a type whose member typedef `type` is the same as `mpl::int_<4>`.

Okay, but in the dimensional analysis example from Boost, they don't have just two things; they have *sequences* `D1` and `D2` of dimensions. (This is a very important point!) Subtracting *sequences* isn't the same thing as subtracting *integers*; consider

```
auto a = std::vector<int>{ 1, 0, 0 };
auto b = std::vector<int>{ 0, 1, 0 };
auto c = (a - b);  // Won't compile!
```

Likewise, in the meta space,

```
using a = mpl::vector<mpl::int_<1>, mpl::int_<0>, mpl::int_<0>>;
using b = mpl::vector<mpl::int_<1>, mpl::int_<0>, mpl::int_<0>>;
using c = mpl::minus<a,b>;  // Won't compile!
```

What we *mean* to say, in the first case, is

```
auto c = std::vector<int>{};
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::back_inserter(c), std::minus<>{});
```

and what we *mean* to say, in the second (meta) case, is

```
using c = mpl::transform<a, b, mpl::minus>::type;  // caveat: we're not done yet
```

Notice that the C++11 `std::transform` takes pairs of iterators `a.begin(), a.end()` instead of just `a`; it takes `b.begin()` but not `b.end()` ([a deficiency that is only now being corrected by the Committee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTeKf5Oek2c)); and it *mutates* `c` via an output iterator, rather than returning a completely new object, for efficiency. MPL's compile-time meta-version takes containers `a` and `b` directly and returns a new container `c`, i.e., it has value semantics, which IMHO is strictly easier to think about.

So, the above is all correct, ***EXCEPT*** for one tiny detail! `mpl::transform` is actually a very generic algorithm, which means that it expects you to spell out the details of the transformation. You said "`mpl::minus`", which means "subtract", okay, but subtract what from what? Subtract the elements of the first sequence from elements of the second? Subtract the second's elements from the first? Subtract `42` from the elements of the second sequence and toss out the first one entirely?

Well, we mean "subtract the second sequence's elements, element-wise, from the first's." Which we write as

```
using c = mpl::transform<a, b, mpl::minus<_1, _2>>::type;
```

We could equally well write

```
using c = mpl::transform<b, a, mpl::minus<_2, _1>>::type;
```

— it would mean the exact same thing.

This generic `transform` algorithm lets us write complicated transforms such as

```
// hide some irrelevant boilerplate behind an alias
template<typename... Ts>
using multiplies_t = mpl::multiplies<Ts...>::type;

// compute c = a^2 + 2ab + 1
using c = mpl::transform<a, b,
    mpl::plus<multiplies_t< _1, _1 >,               // a^2 ...
              multiplies_t< mpl::int_<2>, _1, _2 >, // ... + 2ab ...
              mpl::int_<1>>                         // ... + 1
>::type;
```

Here we can refer to the same element of sequence `a` three times, using the symbol `_1`, while `_2` refers to the corresponding element of sequence `b`.

So, that's the *point* of the symbols `_1` and `_2` in the context of `mpl::transform`. But you're probably still wondering how they're implemented. Well, there's no magic here. They might as well be implemented as

```
template<int> struct _ {};
using _1 = _<1>;
using _2 = _<2>;
```

As long as they get unique, distinguishable entities in C++'s type system, that's all MPL really cares about.

But in fact they're *actually* implemented as typedefs for specializations of [`mpl::arg`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/arg.html), which leads to a nifty trick. Since `_1` is a synonym for `mpl::arg<1>`, we can say

```
_1::apply<A,B,C>::type  is the same type as  A
_2::apply<A,B,C>::type  is the same type as  B
                                ...
```

and I would guess that `mpl::transform` is able to take advantage of that fact internally.

Comment: Journey into madness and back. Very nice answer !